# Trouble computing the shape operator.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, surfaces

> Where have I gone wrong in the following computation of the shape operator of surface?

Suppose we have a surface $M = \{(x,y,f(x,y)) \: | \: (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \}$ for some nice $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$. Let $\phi: \mathbb{R}^2 \to M$ be the obvious parametrisation. The tangent space at a point are given by the span of $\phi_x = (1,0,f_x)$ and $\phi_y = (0,1, f_y)$ (evaluated at that point). The unit normal vector is $N = \frac{\phi_x \times \phi_y}{\|\phi_x \times \phi_y \|} = \gamma (-f_x, -f_y,1)$, where $\gamma = (1+f_x^2+f_y^2)^{-1/2}$.

The coefficients of the first fundamental form are 
$E = \phi_x \cdot \phi_x = 1 + f_x^2$, $F = \phi_x \cdot \phi_y = f_x f_y$, and $G = \phi_y \cdot \phi_y = 1 + f_y^2$. Note that $EG - F^2 = 1 + f_x^2 + f_y^2 = \gamma^{-2}$. The coefficients of the second fundamental form are
$e = N \cdot \phi_{xx} = \gamma f_{xx}$, $f = N \cdot \phi_{xy} = \gamma f_{xy}$, and $g = N \cdot \phi_{xx} = \gamma f_{yy}$.

By the Weingarten equations, we have the shape operator given as

> $\frac{1}{EG -F^2} \begin{bmatrix} e & f \\ f & g\end{bmatrix} 
> \begin{bmatrix} G & -F \\ -F & E\end{bmatrix} = 
> \gamma^3 \begin{bmatrix} f_{xx} & f_{xy} \\ f_{xy} & f_{yy} \end{bmatrix} 
> \begin{bmatrix} 1 + f_y^2 & -f_x f_y \\ -f_x f_y & 1 + f_x^2\end{bmatrix}
> $

This matrix is supposed to be symmetric ([sic] SEE BELOW). However, even choosing a simple $f$, like $f = x^2 - y^2$ yields something not symmetric:

> $\gamma^3 \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix} 
> \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 4y^2 & -4xy \\ -4xy & 1 + 4x^2\end{bmatrix}
> = 2\gamma^3 \begin{bmatrix} 1 + 4y^2 & -4xy \\ 4xy & -(1 + 4x^2)\end{bmatrix}
> $

Please set me straight.

**ADDENDUM:**
I have conflated a few things and tripped over some basic linear algebra. The matrix above need not by symmetric in general. Rather, it is self-adjoint, and the corresponding bilinear form is what is symmetric.

Comment: Product of symmetric matrices may not be symmetric. Why should the shape operator be symmetric?

Comment: @Sanchez:  The shape operator is mos' def symmetric.  Ask your question as a *question*, and see what kind of answers you get!

Comment: @RobertLewis, sorry for the mistake, as I don't know what shape operator is and was looking literally at how this post writes it down. The answer would then be: The shape operator is a symmetric bilinear form, but if you are not choosing orthogonal basis, your matrix would not be symmetric.

Comment: @Sanchez:  well, I didn't mean to come on too strong . . . but yeah, if the basis is not orthonormal, then the matrix of the shape operator will not be symmetric.  But with respect to the induced metric $\langle \, , \, \rangle$ (induced on the surface from $\Bbb R^3$), the shape operator $S$ is symmetric in the sense that $\langle Sx, y \rangle = \langle x, Sy \rangle$ etc. etc. etc.  Cheers, RKL

Comment: @RobertLewis: Don't you mean self-adjoint ( or are the two the same here)?

Comment: One And All:  yes, $\langle Sx, y \rangle = \langle x, Sy \rangle$ is the definition of self-adjoint; but if an orthonormal basis $e_i$ is chosen then the matrix $S_{ij} = \langle e_i, Se_j \rangle$ is symmetric.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shape operator at a point $p$ is a linear map $S_p : T_p M \to T_p M$, so a priori it is meaningless to ask whether it is symmetric. The correct thing to say (as discussed in comments) is that it is self-adjoint with respect to the metric/first fundamental form $g$; that is, $$g(S_p(X),Y) = g(X,S_p(Y)).$$

This is equivalent to the bilinear form associated to $S$ by the metric (the second fundamental form) $$A(X,Y) = g(S_p(X), Y)$$ being symmetric, which you have established is true.

Once you have fixed a basis, the map $S_p$ can be considered as a matrix, at which point it makes sense to ask whether or not it is symmetric. If the basis is orthonormal then the answer will be yes, but it general it will not. Thus the source of your confusion is the fact that the first fundamental form is not (a multiple of) the identity matrix in your chosen coordinates.

Comment: ! Of course. Thank you.